# How to use an array as an index to another array and display entire object react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am starting off with a json file that includes all of my data that I need and from this data I want to use the letters constant as an index to nest the designerNames based on the first letter of the name (need this to be alphabetical) inside 1 object and then display the object

```
  const designerName = designerArray
    .filter(
      (designer, id, designerArray) => designerArray.indexOf(designer) === id
    )
    .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, "fr"));

  const letters = designerArray
    .map((name) => name[0])
    .filter((name, id, designerArray) => designerArray.indexOf(name[0]) === id)
    .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, "fr"));

  const obj = {};

  letters.forEach((element, index) => {
    obj[element] = designerName[index];
  });
```

My expected output from this is :

```
<ul>{letters[0]}</ul>
    <li>{designerName}</li>
<ul>{letters[1]}</ul>
    <li>{designerName}</li>

or 

A
  designerName(asics), designerName (arena)

C
  designerName(Cooper)

N 
  designerName(nike)
... etc etc
```

I got as far as being able to separate all the details I need and combine them into a single object but it is not taking into account the array with the first letters of each brand name.

Would appreciate any help or guidance.. Thank you in advance!

EDIT : Here is the json data that I am pulling from and the results of designerArray as requested

`['Hermes', 'Dakine', 'Dior', 'Hermes', 'Gucci']`

```
[
  {
    "product-name": "Jacket",
    "designer": "Hermes",
    "sizes": ["sm", "md", "lg", "xl"],
    "color": ["black", "green"],
    "description": "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae ullam, saepe explicabo eum vel molestiae veritatis omnis, natus a deleniti, iure eligendi quam quisquam maiores repellendus aspernatur atque fuga consectetur.",
    "price": "$532"
  },
  {
    "product-name": "Jacket2",
    "designer": "Dakine",
    "sizes": ["sm", "md", "lg", "xl"],
    "color": ["black", "green"],
    "description": "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae ullam, saepe explicabo eum vel molestiae veritatis omnis, natus a deleniti, iure eligendi quam quisquam maiores repellendus aspernatur atque fuga consectetur.",
    "price": "$532"
  },
  {
    "product-name": "Sweater",
    "designer": "Dior",
    "sizes": ["sm", "md", "lg", "xl"],
    "color": ["green"],
    "description": "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae ullam, saepe explicabo eum vel molestiae veritatis omnis, natus a deleniti, iure eligendi quam quisquam maiores repellendus aspernatur atque fuga consectetur.",
    "price": "$532"
  },
  {
    "product-name": "Shirt",
    "designer": "Hermes",
    "sizes": ["sm", "md", "xl"],
    "color": ["white"],
    "description": "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae ullam, saepe explicabo eum vel molestiae veritatis omnis, natus a deleniti, iure eligendi quam quisquam maiores repellendus aspernatur atque fuga consectetur.",
    "price": "$532"
  },
  {
    "product-name": "Pants",
    "designer": "Gucci",
    "sizes": ["sm", "md", "lg"],
    "color": ["black"],
    "description": "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae ullam, saepe explicabo eum vel molestiae veritatis omnis, natus a deleniti, iure eligendi quam quisquam maiores repellendus aspernatur atque fuga consectetur.",
    "price": "$532"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the content of the `designerArray`? can you put an example of what data structure you expect to extract from it?

Comment: @Pipe just added it!

Comment: The array with names is what you expect to extract? can you clarify a bit?

Comment: Yep, sorry for the confusion.

So for the letters constant it is taking the first letter of each string in the designerName array, and the designerName is just taking the json data and only outputting the name.

I would like to display the first letter(excluding duplicates) and nested inside is the names of the designers that have that first letter in their name so it would look like -

D:
  Dior, Dakine

G:
  Gucci

N: 
  Nike

Comment: Adding that this is a list that is also sorted to be alphabetical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can (using `Array.reduce` function) extract first letter and group them by that letter.

Does this work for you?

```js
const designerArray = [
{
    "product-name": "Pants3",
    "designer": "Giovanni",
    "sizes": ["sm", "md", "lg"],
    "color": ["black"],
    "description": "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae ullam, saepe explicabo eum vel molestiae veritatis omnis, natus a deleniti, iure eligendi quam quisquam maiores repellendus aspernatur atque fuga consectetur.",
    "price": "$532"
  },
  {
    "product-name": "Jacket",
    "designer": "Hermes",
    "sizes": ["sm", "md", "lg", "xl"],
    "color": ["black", "green"],
    "description": "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae ullam, saepe explicabo eum vel molestiae veritatis omnis, natus a deleniti, iure eligendi quam quisquam maiores repellendus aspernatur atque fuga consectetur.",
    "price": "$532"
  },
  {
    "product-name": "Jacket2",
    "designer": "Dakine",
    "sizes": ["sm", "md", "lg", "xl"],
    "color": ["black", "green"],
    "description": "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae ullam, saepe explicabo eum vel molestiae veritatis omnis, natus a deleniti, iure eligendi quam quisquam maiores repellendus aspernatur atque fuga consectetur.",
    "price": "$532"
  },
  {
    "product-name": "Pants",
    "designer": "Gucci",
    "sizes": ["sm", "md", "lg"],
    "color": ["black"],
    "description": "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae ullam, saepe explicabo eum vel molestiae veritatis omnis, natus a deleniti, iure eligendi quam quisquam maiores repellendus aspernatur atque fuga consectetur.",
    "price": "$532"
  },
{
    "product-name": "Pants2",
    "designer": "Domeco",
    "sizes": ["sm", "md", "lg"],
    "color": ["black"],
    "description": "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae ullam, saepe explicabo eum vel molestiae veritatis omnis, natus a deleniti, iure eligendi quam quisquam maiores repellendus aspernatur atque fuga consectetur.",
    "price": "$532"
  }
];

designerNames = designerArray.map(d => d.designer).sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, "fr"));

console.log(designerNames);

const orderedByLetter = designerNames.reduce((acc, name) => {
   const firstLetter = name[0];
   acc[firstLetter] = acc[firstLetter] || []; //Set if previously not set
   acc[firstLetter].push(name);
   return acc;
}, {})

console.log(orderedByLetter);
```

Comment: Solved! This is the output I was looking for, I believe I got myself confused by thinking I needed to separate the first letter of the strings as its individual array first before trying to figure out a way to combine them together. 

Thank you!